# Cylone IV Family name does not appear on Board selection

Tags: intel, quartus

On Quartus Prime Lite Edition I cannot see the family name for Cyclone IV  on board selection. However, it appears on device. Does anyone know why I am having this issue? I need to select the family name Cyclone IV and DE2_115.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxke4.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71j7V.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the device list you simply need to select Cyclone® IV EP4CE115 to use your DE2-115 board.

On the board list you have only some predefined commercial boards available. It is possible to add new ones, but as far as I remember, there is no file available online for DE2-115 board.